# react: CSS breaks using classList in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

CSS and app breaks in Edge and Internet Explorer for the following code-

```
componentDidMount() {
  const styles = require('./GettingStarted.scss');
  document.getElementById('bodyTag').classList = '';
  document.getElementById('bodyTag').classList.add(styles.GettingStartedContainerBody);
  document.getElementById('content').classList.remove(styles.AppContainerBody);
  document.getElementById('content').classList = '';
  document.getElementById('content').classList.remove(styles.AppContainerBodyWithoutLogin);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (!this.props.checked && nextProps.checked) {
    let queryString = '';
    const windowLocation = window.location.href;
    const queryStringStartIndex = windowLocation.indexOf('?');
    if (queryStringStartIndex > 0) {
      queryString = windowLocation.substring(queryStringStartIndex,windowLocation.length);
    }

    if(nextProps.result[0].status === '0') {
      browserHistory.push(config.BASE_URL + '/userdetail' + queryString);
    } else if(nextProps.result[0].status === '1') {
      browserHistory.push(config.BASE_URL + '/signuplogin' + queryString);
    }
  }
}

render() {
  const { checking, checkingError, fields: {emailid}} = this.props;
  const styles = require('./GettingStarted.scss');
  const pmdLogo = require('../../../static/plexusmd-logo.png');
  return (
    <div className={styles.gettingStartedPage}>
      <Helmet {...config.app.head} title="Getting Started | PlexusMD" />
      <div className="gettingStartedForm margin-top-bottom-40">
        <div className="headerLogoMenuContainer text-center margin-bottom-30">
          <IndexLink className="brandlogo" to={config.BASE_URL + '/gettingstarted'} >
            <img className="brand" src={pmdLogo} width="80" height="25" title={config.app.title} alt={config.app.title} />
          </IndexLink>
        </div>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
          <h2 className="orange font22 text-left text-bold text-uppercase margin-top-0 margin-bottom-50 margin-left-right-20">Getting started</h2>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="password" className="control-label gray">What's your Email address?</label>
            <div className="input-group">
              <input type="text" id="emailid" name="emailid" ref="emailid" placeholder="Email address" value={this.props.emailid} className="form-control text-lowercase" {...emailid}/>
              {!emailid.error && <span id="emailid" className="input-group-addon input-group-icon"><i className="icon ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-size green"/></span>}
              { emailid.error && emailid.dirty && <div id="emailid" className="red smaller margin-0-auto">Enter a valid Email</div>}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className="text-right">
              {checkingError && <p className="loginError red text-left">{checkingError}</p>}
              {!checking && <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} disabled={emailid.error}>NEXT
              </button>}
              {checking && <button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={checking}>WAIT</button>}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="clear"></div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="clear"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The background color is not updating in this page, as well as the input field is disabled i.e., cannot type into the field unless I remove the props in the `<input>` tag.

`AppContainerBody` and `AppContainerBodyWithoutLogin` css classes are inherited from `app.scss`. `GettingStartedContainerBody` classlist belongs to `GettingStarted.scss`

I am adding these classlists in almost every file in my React app. The app works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but I get this error in console:

> Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode

[Link](https://www.plexusmd.com/md/) to the app and [App.scss](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2lLy-Ta6I8nYmMtSGpRVmQ5dzA) and [GettingStarted.scss](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2lLy-Ta6I8nWkFNNWFPS0ttLUE).

**Versions:**
React: 0.14.2
Edge: 40.15063.674.0

Answer (score 0):

Move all require statements out of your functions to the top of your file.

So instead of calling `const styles = require('./GettingStarted.scss');` in each functions you want to use your styles, only import it once.

Like:

```
require('./GettingStarted.scss');
// or
import './GettingStarted.scss';
```

---

`classList` cannot be changed directly. Use `classList.add` and `classList.remove` or change the attribute class via `className = ''` or `.setAttribute( 'class', '' )`

---

Also try to minimize DOM selections/code duplicates by saving a selection to a variable, e.g.:

```
const bodyTag = document.getElementById('bodyTag');
// further instructions for #bodyTag
const content = document.getElementById('content');
// further instruction for #content
```

Comment: .setAttribute() or changing the className doesn't seem to solve the problem, still getting the same error. Also, will try to improve my code using your suggestions.

Comment: The error occurs in the same file: `gettingstarted.js`. I tried all other files in the browser, they all work fine in Edge and IE.Only this file is crashing.

Comment: Have you moved all `require` statements to the top of your file?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed. The input field is still disabled and the background-color is not changing.